# Oracle SQL sort by ternary operation

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting

I'm trying to sort records in ORACLE SQL such that all strings that contain the phrase 'VENT' are sorted to the top, and the others are sorted by length.

```
   Select D1.MENU_TEXT
   from IMPRESSIONS_DEF D1
   order by IFF(instr(D1.MENU_TEXT, 'VENT'),1, LENGTH(D1.MENU_TEXT));
```

I tried this, but it fails with "IFF" invalid identifier.  I also tried

```
   Select D1.MENU_TEXT, iff(D1.MENU_TEXT like '%VENT%', 1, 200) as k
   from IMPRESSIONS_DEF D1
   order by k + Length(D1.Menu_Text);
```

and it says "missing right parenthesis"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `case` expression:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN MENU_TEXT LIKE '%VENT%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),
         LENGTH(D1.MENU_TEXT);
```

`CASE` is standard SQL.  `IIF()` is bespoke SQL only used by a few databases.